# Evaluating $\int_1^{\infty}x\: \text{erfc}(a+b \log (x)) \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, closed-form, error-function

I am trying to evaluate the following integral

> $$I = \int_1^{\infty } x \mathop{erfc}(a + b \log (x)) \, dx$$

where $a$, $b$ are some positive constants.

Using the substitution $t = \log (x)$, the integral transforms to 
$$I = \int_0^{\infty } \mathrm{e}^{2t} \mathop{erfc}(a + b t) \, dt.$$
I am not quite sure how to proceed from here. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

**Edit**
let further $y= a + b t$, then the integral changes to 
$$I = \frac{1}{b}\int_a^{\infty } \mathrm{e}^{\frac{2}{b}\left(y - a\right)} \mathop{erfc}(y) \, dy.$$

Comment: A shift $a+bt=y$ followed by an integration by parts will solve ur problem

Comment: @tired, Thank you I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Integrating by parts, one easily gets
$$
\int_0^{\infty } e^{2t} \mathop{erfc}(a + b t)\,dt=\left. \frac{ e^{2t} }2\mathop{erfc}(a + b t)\right|_0^\infty -\frac12\int_0^{\infty} e^{2t} \left( -\frac{2 b e^{-(a+b t)^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right) dt
$$ giving

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_0^{\infty } e^{2t} \mathop{erfc}(a + b t) \, dt&=-\frac{\mathop{erfc}(a)}2+\frac b{\sqrt{\pi }}\int_0^{\infty } e^{2t}e^{-(a+b t)^2} dt
> \\\\&=-\frac{\mathop{erfc}(a)}2+\frac12e^{\large \frac{1-2 a b}{b^2}} \mathop{erfc}\left(a-\frac{1}{b}\right).
> \end{align}
> $$